# Ошибка 'float is required' не может возвращать значение функции

Tags: python, функции, list, float

```
    import math
def L(a, b,eps):
    list_of_L = [] 
    min = 0
    while a <= b:
        min = math.fabs(10*a-10*math.pow(a,1/4)-20)
        list_of_L.append(min)
        a+=eps
        list_of_L.sort()
    return list_of_L[len(list_of_L)-1]
def f(x):
    return 5*math.pow(x,2)-8*math.pow(x,(5/4))-20*x
def F(list):
    min = f(x)
    list.append(min)
    list.sort()
    return list[0]
minimums_of_func = []    
a = float(input('Введіть a: '))
b = float(input('Введіть b: '))
eps = float(input('Введіть точність обчислення: '))
print(L(a,b,eps))
h = (2*eps)/L(a,b,eps)
n = int(math.ceil((b-a)/h))
print(n)
x = []
x.append(a + h/2)
i = 1
while i <= n - 2:
    x_previous = x[i-1]
    x.append(x[i-1] + h + (f(x_previous) - F(minimums_of_func))/L)
    i+=1
print(F(x[n-2]))
```

Comment: А вы не могли бы привести весь код, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку. Я только что попробовал - ошибок нет, функция возвращает float.

Comment: да, подождите немного

Comment: проблема наверное в функции F(list)

Comment: И еще 2 вопроса - какая версия python и какие начальные данные надо ввести, чтобы получить ошибку?

Comment: В прошлый раз вы писали, что ошибка в функции f(x)?

Comment: a = 3 b = 3.5 eps = 0.1

Comment: def F(list,x):
    min = f(x)
    list.append(min)
    list.sort()
    return list[0]

Comment: x.append(x[i-1] + h + (f(x_previous) - F(minimums_of_func,x_previous))/L)

Comment: TypeError на строке 31: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'function'
Ошибка типов: невозможно выполнить операцию '/' с объектами типов 'float' и 'function'

Comment: Так вы в функцию f(x) передаете list, а не число.

Comment: это как f(x[i-1])?

Comment: while i <= n - 2:
    x_previous = x[i-1]
    F_f = F(minimums_of_func,x_previous)
    x.append(x[i-1] + h + f(x_previous) - F_f/L)
    i+=1

Comment: Добавьте в f(x) перед `return` код `print(x)` и вы все увидите.